# No sounds in asterisk when call to voicemail

Tags: asterisk, voip

I just started to play around with asterisk. Currently it is installed on CentOS 7 and version of Asterisk is 13.

This is what I get when I call directly to voicemail from Zoiper

```
-- Executing [8500@demo:2] VoiceMailMain("SIP/2001-00000028", "@demo") in new stack
-- <SIP/2001-00000028> Playing 'vm-login.gsm' (language 'en')
-- <SIP/2001-00000028> Playing 'vm-password.gsm' (language 'en')
-- Incorrect password '' for user '2001' (context = demo)
-- <SIP/2001-00000028> Playing 'vm-incorrect-mailbox.gsm' (language 'en')
   ....
```

This is what I have in extension.conf

```
exten => 8500,1,Answer
exten => 8500,2,VoiceMailMain()
exten => 8500,3,Hangup()
```

This is in voicemail.conf

```
[demo]

2001 => Demo Test, demo@127.0.0.1
```

and this is the user in sip.conf

```
[general]

port = 5060
bindaddr = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
allow=all           
context = bogon-calls ; Send SIP callers that we don't know about here

[2001]

type=friend           ; This device takes and makes calls
username=demo_test         ; Username on device
secret=1234 ; Password for device
host=dynamic          ; This host is not on the same IP addr every time
context=demo      ; Inbound calls from this host go here
mailbox=100
```

In `/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en` are all the .gsm files..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check firewall rtp ports(see rtp.conf for port list)